# Eclipse - Unable to find Faces config editor

Tags: jsf, faces-config

I am using eclipse with ADT, and installed JSF configs for new (non-android) J2EE project. I setup all the components, changed project facets (to add JSF) but I am not able to find Faces config editor for Faces-config.xml to create Managed beans etc., even in the external editors window. Can someone suggest what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing Eclipse JEE Kepler without the ADT is not an option? I also use Eclipse ADT for Android Development and another Eclipse Installation for some of my JEE - Projects.
In Eclipse ADT the menu entry is missing whilst it is under New->JSF in Eclipse JEE Kepler .

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou, That worked previous I installed Eclipse standard (after ADT) and the standard one merged with ADT